# Changing values from derived classes

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

```
class BaseClass
{
    public int Field = 1;
}
class DerivedA : BaseClass
{
    public int SetField6()
    {
        return this.Field = 6;
    }
}
class DerivedB : BaseClass
{
    public int SetField16()
    {
        return this.Field = 16;
    }
}

BaseClass x = new BaseClass();
int xField = x.Field;

DerivedA y = new DerivedA();
int yField = y.SetField6();

DerivedB z = new DerivedB();
int zField = z.SetField16();

int baseField = new BaseClass().Field;
```

In this scenario when the value of `Field` is changed in the `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` classes, the value of `Field` in the `BaseClass` class is not changed.  So the value of `baseField` is still `1`.

- Is it possible to change the value of `Field` in the class, `BaseClass` from a derived class?
- Is there a design pattern for this scenario and what is it called?

Comment: Why would you give us example code using cryptic names for everything? Do you know how **hard** it is to follow what you're saying?

Comment: Ok... 20 minutes later and I've refactored and rephrased everything... hopefully it should be easier to read for everyone else now.

Comment: What excellent service, @Jeff. People should dine here more often

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate each object, it creates its own memory in heap till it roots i.e Object class. And all the memebers in every class of the heirarchy is created in stack (if its valuetype).

Hence its different in each case.

Answer (score 1):

First, what might be the fix: make the field you want changed by subclasses `static` in the base class.  I'm not sure if this will really give you the behavior you expect, because it's unclear just what that behavior is.  If you do this, **every** instance will share the same value.

Second, this is all unclear because (I think) you're confusing classes with instances here.

To use a pretty common metaphor for this, it's the difference between the blueprint for a house and the house itself.

The question you just asked is:  if I make a house from blueprint Z, and I break a window in that house, why aren't any windows broken in a new house made from the same blueprint?

The house in this metaphor is the instance (`x`), the blueprint is the class(`BaseClass`).

Comment: Problem is that after that change, the code cannot access that member with an instance reference anymore, and it looks like the OP really wants to use instance references.

Comment: Are you really able to understand what the OP wants :) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make Field in BaseClass static to get what you want (although I really can't understand what you are trying to achieve)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** *Is it possible to change the value of Field in the class, BaseClass from a derived class?*

You have actually done that in your scenario, but it is hidden by that last line of code (because you are instantiating a new object which gets a fresh Field setup to be 1). So, instead of calling:

```
 int baseField = new BaseClass().Field;
```

Use this:

```
 int baseField = y.Field; // baseField is now = 6 because Field was changed earlier by y.SetField6()
```

This way, you can actually see that the value of the base member Field has been modified by an object constructed from a derived class (the actual modification was done by calling y.SetField6()).

**2.** *Is there a design pattern for this scenario and what is it called?*

Yes, it is called **object inheritance**.